# API reference to WebKit WebView implementation in GTK (Python)

Tags: python, documentation, webkit, gtk, pygobject

I'm working on a Python Gtk3 app on Ubuntu, which primarily uses `WebView` from WebKit. I couldn't find all the methods available to WebView object in python, currently I only know its `open()` method, so, where can I get detailed reference to all its methods, including some documentation on handling cookies and user password saving, etc?

I went through http://webkitgtk.org/ but I couldn't find Python related API, or (I might have missed it out).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of GOBject Introspection, you should have access to every public class/method/function available in the WebKit.  Hence, the original API documentation should help.

To know every method available, you can even use the classic help from Python.  For instance:

```
$ python
>>> from gi.repository import WebKit2
>>> help(WebKit2.WebView)
```

Now, you can match the method names against the documentation for other languages (likely Objective-C).

Answer (score 3):

In addition the API reference on [webkitgtk.org](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/ch02.html) is pretty good too, even though it is not Python specific. But if you're used to read GTK documentations it's pretty easy to use it for Python applications.